# Yahoo Group and Bitbucket/GitHub?

Tags: git, yahoo, mailing-list

I would like to automatically send email notification of GIT push action on Bitbucket or GitHub. I used Google group for it, and it works well. But since Google is blocked in China, it is inconvenient to manage the mailing list. So I want to switch to Yahoo group which appears like Google group.

My question is how to add Bitbucket email "commits-noreply@bitbucket.org" in Yahoo group?

Thanks!